# Does 'seed' of a uniform random number generator same for different software

Tags: random-variables, uniform-distribution

As the question says, does the 'seed' for uniform random number generator same for different software, for example, Matlab or any other software.

The reason for asking this question is that I used a 'seed' for a simulation in Matlab. I will refer it in my journal article. If someone wants to implement my paper in another language (e.g. C/C++/Python), does the same seed work for him/her?

Comment: You should really be asking programming related questions on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I thought it has to do with math as the question deals with uniform random number generator !

Comment: It just seems like you will get a better answer from programmers, not mathematicians :) I mean a seed it generally generated from a computer hardware variable like time, memory use, CPU etc. right?

Comment: oh ok....make sense. thanks

Comment: Please don't let my comment(s) deter you from asking questions! Just have a think about audience. :D

Comment: It is unlikely you will get the same results from different software.  First, there are many different PRNG (pseudo-random number generator) algorithms.  Second, even if the basic algorithms are the same, there may be differences in details of implementation that will cause different results.  If you want to be helpful in your article, you might state the algorithm used by Matlab, if it is documented. Disclaimer: I don't know much about Matlab.